# Передать имя столбца через переменную | MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Нужно передать в хранимую процедуру имя столбца как переменную. Пытаюсь хотя б выполнить MSSQL MS запрос, не выходит. Вот мой запрос

```html
DECLARE @COLNAME NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @COLNAME = 'Student'
DECLARE @TABLE NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @TABLE = 'IndexData'

DECLARE @QRY NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @QRY = 'UPDATE '+@TABLE+' SET '+@COLNAME+' = true Where Lastname = Smith'
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @QRY
```

У меня ругается на параметр Smith, пишет что неправильное имя столбца, хотя причем тут столбец если Smith это значение столбца

`Invalid column name 'Smith'.`

Как мне обновить значение столбца в таблице, при этом передать название столбца как переменную.

По факту это должен быть синоним вот такого запроса

```html
BEGIN
UPDATE IndexData
SET Student = 'true'
WHERE Lastname = 'Smith'
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SET @QRY = 'UPDATE '+@TABLE+' SET '+@COLNAME+' = true Where Lastname = ''Smith'''
```

или, возможно, так

```
SET @QRY = 'UPDATE '+@TABLE+' SET '+@COLNAME+' = ''true'' Where Lastname = ''Smith'''
```

в зависимости от того, какой тип у поля `Student`.

---

> если захочу еще переменную true передавать как параметр, когда делаю
>
> 'SET @QRY = 'UPDATE '+@TABLE+' SET '+@COLNAME+' = '+@VALUE+' Where Lastname = ''Smith''''
>
> ругается 'The data types nvarchar and bit are incompatible in the add
>   operator.'

```
SET @QRY = 'UPDATE '+@TABLE+' SET '+@COLNAME+' = '''+@IIF(@VALUE,'true','false')+''' Where Lastname = ''Smith'''
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает. Подскажите, если захочу еще переменную true передавать как параметр, когда делаю 'SET @QRY = 'UPDATE '+@TABLE+' SET '+@COLNAME+' =  '+@VALUE+' Where Lastname = ''Smith''''  ругается 'The data types nvarchar and bit are incompatible in the add operator.'

Comment: @FX_Sektor `... @COLNAME+' = '''+IIF(@VALUE,'true','false')+''' Where ...`

Comment: возможна sql инъекция. Лучше пошлите условный ID колонки и воспользуйтесь стандартным sql  без динамического. Если это скрипт для внутреннего пользования, то можно и так.